# What Would be the Correct SELECT Statement for This?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

```
SELECT *
  FROM notifications
  INNER JOIN COMMENT
    ON COMMENT.id = notifications.source_id
      WHERE idblog IN (SELECT blogs_id
        FROM blogs
        WHERE STATUS = "active")
  INNER JOIN reportmsg
    ON reportmsg.msgid = notifications.source_id
      WHERE uid =: uid
  ORDER BY notificationid DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

Here I am `INNER JOIN`ing `notifications` with `comment` and `reportmsg`; then filtering content with `WHERE`.

But my problem is that for the first `INNER JOIN` [i.e, with `comment`], before joining `notifications` with `comment`, I want to match `notifications.idblog` with `blogs.blogs_id` *and* `SELECT` only those rows where `blogs.status = "active"`.

For better understanding of the code above:

[image: ER diagram]

Here, for `INNER JOIN`, with `comment` I want to `SELECT` only those rows in `notifications` whose `idblog` matches `blogs.blogs_id` *and* has `status = "active"`.

The second `INNER JOIN` with `reportmsg` needs not to be altered.  I.e, it only filters through `uid`.

Comment: The language you use to interact with relational databases is called SQL, not PHP. I've edited your question accordingly.

Comment: Since `COMMENT` is a keyword, I would be careful and put backtics around it.

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə check my answer whether it satisfies or not...and tell what I have missed in my answer..

Answer (score 4):

As you can see from the image below, you can just need to merge other tables to notifications table using `LEFT JOIN` like that:

```
SELECT n.notificationid, n.uid, n.idblog, n.source_id, 
       b.blogs_id, b.status,
       c.id, 
       r.msgid
       -- ... and the other columns you want
FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN blogs b ON b.blogs_id = n.idblog AND b.STATUS = "active" AND n.uid =: uid
LEFT JOIN comment c ON c.id = n.source_id    
LEFT JOIN reportmsg r ON r.msgid = n.source_id
ORDER BY n.notificationid DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

[image: SQL JOINS]

Comment: No point in `LEFT JOIN blogs b` if you have `WHERE b.STATUS = "active"`...this effectively reverts it to an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Arth You are riight, I updated my answer and move conditions in "*WHERE*" clause to "*ON*". Thanks.

Comment: Cheers, but now you are getting all notifications, comments and reportmsgs and only filtering matched blogs.. pretty sure this isn't what OP wants.

Comment: Image most likely from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins#answer-16598900).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen Yes, but the question is not "Where is the image from?". If you have any idea please post your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MuratYıldız I posted the link mostly just because it is a very useful question/answer, but also because you should have cited the source (not doing so may leave people thinking that you created the image, which you did not do).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I think there is no need to create a diagram from scratch while there are many useful ones on the internet provided that there is no copyright for the related image. On the other hand, I think most of the diagram has  also been used as it was on this page and even if I had wanted to post the owner of this image I could have not know if the owner of this diagram is the one who posted the answer on the page you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need/reason to *filter before the second join* because you only use inner joins and then the order of joins and WHERE-conditions don't matter:

```
SELECT n.*, c.*, r.*
FROM notifications AS n
JOIN COMMENT  as c 
  ON n.source_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN blogs as b
  ON n.idblogs = b.blogs_id
 AND B.STATUS = 'active'
JOIN reportmsg AS R
  ON n.source_id = r.msgid 
WHERE uid =: uid
ORDER BY notificationid DESC
LIMIT 20
```

You can switch the order of joins, you can move `B.STATUS = 'active'` into the join-condition, but all queries will return the same result. (After the edit it's a `LEFT JOIN`, of course now the result differs)

And of course you shouldn't use `*`, better list only the columns you actually need.

Comment: alone `join` does not select any row, using `LEFT JOIN` for comment and reportmg and `INNER JOIN` for blogs worked but condition `where STATUS='actiive'` applies for both `comment` table and `reportmsg` is there any way I can apply that condition only on comment table?

Comment: @bɪˈɡɪnə: Would have been easier if you added some example data :-)  You probably need to move the `STATUS='active'` into the join, I'll edit my answer..

Answer (score 1):

if query optimizer does its work, it does not matter where you put filtering statement in `INNER JOIN` case but in the `LEFT JOIN` it has effects. Putting filtering statement in `LEFT JOIN` conditions cause table filtered at first and joined after while putting filtering statement in `WHERE` clause will filter results of join. Hence, if you want to use `LEFT JOIN` your query must look like:

```
  SELECT nt.*
  FROM notifications nt
  LEFT JOIN Blogs bg on nt.blogs_id = bg.blogs_id and bg.STATUS = "active"
  LEFT JOIN COMMENT cm ON cm.id = nt.source_id         
  LEFT JOIN reportmsg rm ON rm.msgid = nt.source_id
  WHERE uid =: uid
  ORDER BY nt.notificationid DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you are after here.. while your table diagram is useful, you should really supply some sample data and an expected result even if it is just a couple of dummy rows for each table.

Queries work row by row, both INNER JOINs are applied to the same notification row and non-matching rows are discarded.

Any filter applies to both JOIN and any returned rows must have a match in BOTH comment and reportmsg.

Perhaps you want two LEFT JOINs that can apply different filters and guessing from the table names perhaps it could look like this:

```
   SELECT *
     FROM notifications n
LEFT JOIN blogs b
       ON n.blogId = b.blogs_id
LEFT JOIN comment c
       ON c.id = n.source_id
      AND b.status = "Active"
LEFT JOIN reportmsg rm
       ON rm.msgid = n.source_id
    WHERE n.uid =: uid
      AND (c.id IS NOT NULL OR rm.msgid IS NOT NULL)
 ORDER BY n.notificationid DESC
    LIMIT 20
```

You also should work on your naming convention:

- notifications, comment -> pick either plural or singular table names
- notifications.notificationid, comment.id -> pick adding table name to id
- notificationid, source_id -> pick underscore or no separation
- idblog, notificationid -> pick prepending or appending id

Currently you pretty much have to look up every id field every time you want to use one.

Answer (score -1):

You should change your query to this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM notifications 
INNER JOIN comment ON comment.id = notifications.source_id 
INNER JOIN reportmsg ON reportmsg.msgid=notifications.source_id 
LEFT JOIN blogs ON notifications.idblog = blogs.blogs_id
WHERE blogs.status = 'active'
ORDER BY notificationid DESC 
LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: thanx but i want  `status='active'` condition only for first inner join

Comment: If the rest of your query is working, but only this part is not, then why don't you put status = 'active' after the INNER JOIN statement. Like this: `INNER JOIN comment ON comment.id = notifications.source_id  AND status = 'active'`

Comment: `"INNER JOIN comment ON (comment.id = notifications.source_id AND comment.status='active')"`..considering your comments table has the status column.

Comment: No point in `LEFT JOIN blogs` if you have `WHERE blogs.status = "active"`...this effectively reverts it to an `INNER JOIN`